# Command line tool to convert a jar to an executable?

Tags: java, windows, jar, executable

I can convert a Java `.class` file into a `.jar` file by the following command:

```
jar cvf Hello.jar Hello.class
```

Now I want to convert the `.jar` to a Windows executable (.exe).
Is there any similar command or any command line tool to do this?

I am developing an automatic tool to compile the .class file to an .exe without any human intervention so GUI-based tools will not work.

Answer (score 5):

There are several options out there :

- [Jar2Exe](http://www.jar2exe.com/)
- [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html)
- [Executor](http://mpowers.net/executor/)
- [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)
- [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/)
- [JCGO](http://www.ivmaisoft.com/jcgo/index.htm)
- [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [JexePack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html)

The last one(JexePack) is maybe the more closer to your needs since it is a command line tool :

> JexePack is a command line tool (great for automated scripting) that
>   allows you to package your Java application (class files), optionally
>   along with its resources (like GIF/JPG/TXT/etc), into a single
>   compressed 32-bit Windows EXE, which runs using Sun's Java Runtime
>   Environment. Both console and windowed applications are supported.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed JexePack, I can see jexepack.exe !! do u know the command to convert .jar file to .exe ?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar look at the documentation on the official site ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/). Bonus: There is also a maven plugin for it.

Update: To run as command line see the [command line reference manual](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jsmooth-doc.html#N102A9).

Comment: Thanks but the screen shots of JSmooth shows GUI, I want a simple command like :-  >>>Jsmooth Hello.exe Hello.jar

Comment: Screenshots may show a gui, but given that there is a maven plugin for it that I in fact use, I can tell you it is not gui based.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).  Easy to add to an Ant or shell script.  There is a GUI to facilitate building the config file (if you need it), then reference the config file in the script.

Comment: Thanks but its asking me to edit .xml file any simple command to achieve -> .jar to .exe ?